# textarea post value getting cut off by &= in url

Tags: php, post, textarea

I have a textarea that submits its value to a php page onkeypress. the problem is, if you type a url like so into the textarea:

```
http://website.com/index.php?value=1&othervalue=2
```

the php page receiving the textarea data interprets &othervalue=2 to be the cutoff point for the text area as if othervalue=2 was another post variable it is supposed to receive. If this doesn't make sense I will try to explain it differently. Any ideas to get around this?????

Comment: Please post some code for a clearer explanation, I don't understand what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're using ajax (since you're using onkeypress), make sure you always escape your data properly.  See [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

Answer (score 3):

1. That's GET data, not POST data.
2. If `value` is supposed to equal `1&othervalue=2`, you need to [`urlencode`](http://php.net/urlencode) the ampersand, resulting in `1%26othervalue%3D2`.